# Application Insights - Unit testing, Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a MVC project which uses the application insight and it is working fine and it is capturing all the telemetric details in azure under the proper dashboard.

I am trying to test this functionality through the unit test project, from the unit test project i am calling the class file which is present in the MVC project.,

It is working and executing the the Funciton1() but these values are not diaplaying under the dashboard...

Any suggestions..

Application 1 -> Testproject C# Class project

```
[TestMethod]

 Method1()
{
    MVCAppinsightCls a = new MVCAppinsightCls();
    a.Function1();
}
```

MVC WebApplication

```
Class MVCAppinsightCls
{

  Funciton1()
 {

    TelemetryClient o = new TelemetryClient();
    o.trackEvent("someName");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the method like this from your Test project, then your Test project is your host so what you need is to add all the configurations related to your App Insights in your Test Peoject too (Instumentation Key settings and all other stuff) so that it sends the logs to App Insights.

You need the ApplicationInsights.config file and also you need to add the nuget packages related to App Insights to your Unit Test project.